# Why does the -webkit-keyframes feature of CSS3 not validate in HTML5?

Tags: html, css

This animation feature does not validate when the css file is uploaded in http://validator.w3.org/ The error says that this `-webkit-keyframes` is inactive, although it is providing the rotating animation I expect.

Comment: Because the validator is broken.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by that? It still works perfectly fine in the browser.

Comment: I mean that it's a bug in the validator.

Comment: In general CSS validation is a bit of red herring. The CSS spec is one of the more fluid aspects of the languages of the web, and so it's hard for validators to be kept up to date. If your CSS works in the browser, trust it, you don't need it to be certified as valid :)

Comment: I am just worrying about my professor who would like to have 0 errors in the CSS of the website project that he gave us. I think it has something to do with compatibility on all the browsers. This  http://validator.w3.org/ website has been designed by mozilla, so that may be the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vendor prefixed properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords) (i.e. those starting with `-foo-`) are not valid CSS.

They are *experimental* features designed using a naming convention (which is blessed by the CSS specification) that won't conflict with future standards or experiments by other vendors who use the same convention.

They are there so that new features can be tested out, not for general use in public web pages. The CSS specification says:

> Authors should avoid vendor-specific extensions